# python:How can I print out my file lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files, temporary-directory

I have this function.

```
def write_file(tmpdir, filename):
    full_file_name = tmpdir/filename 
with openFile(filename) as p:
    lines = p.readlines()
return lines
```

I have pass my filename. For example file.txt ,and there can be written everything.
How can I print out all of the lines of the file.txt file in this write_file function?

Comment: `for line in lines: print(line)` or `print(p.read())`? And I think your code is not indented properly. And `full_file_name ` variable is not being use anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Generic syntax to print the file lines

```py
with open(your_file, 'r') as f:
    print(''.join([for x in f.readlines()]))
```